# Chinese character encoding with swift

Tags: swift, utf-8

```
let chineseWord = "好" 
let encodedWord = chineseWord.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)! // outputs <e5a5bd>
```

I want the output to be `%e5%a5%bd` but XCode says that `encodedWord` is of type `NSData` and therefore I'm not able to loop through it and add `%` signs as it isn't a string. Is there a way to convert `NSData` to strings? And also if it isn't too much trouble could someone give a brief explanation of what `NSData` actually is? I read the documentation and I can't really grasp the concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a string representation of the data in your NSData object is available, you can get it by calling "debugDescription" on it.

```
let str = encodedWord.debugDescription
```

Then you can loop or anything else on this string as you see fit.

```
for char in str {
    println(char)
}
```